# Web Server being used as File Storage - How to improvise?

Tags: backup, webserver, storage, fileserver, contingency

I am making a DR plan for a web application which is hosted on a production web server. Now that web server also acts as a file storage for storing the feed uploads files (used by the web application as input) and report files( output of web application processing).  Now if the web server goes down , the files data is also lost, so need to design a solution and give recomendations which eliminates this single point of failiure. 
I have thought of some recommendations as follows-
1) Use a seperate file server however it requires a new resources 
2) Attach a data volume mounted on the web server which is mapped to some network filer ( network storage) which can be used to store the feeds and reports. In case the web server goes down , the network filer can be mounted and attached to the contingency web server.
3) There is one more web server which is load balanced however that is not currently being used as file storage , and if we can implement a feature which takes the back up of the file data regularly to that load balanced second web server , we can start using that incase the first web server goes down. The back up can be done through a back up script, or seperate windows service , or some scheduling job for scheduling the backup job every night.

Please help me to review above or suggest new recommendations to help eliminate this single point of failiure problem on the web server. It would be highly appreciated?
Regards
Kapil

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used [Amazon's S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store the "output" data of web and non-web applications. Using a service like that is beneficial from the single-point-of-failure perspective because then any other instance of that web application, or a different type of client, on the same server or in a completely different datacenter still has access to the same output files. Another similar option is [Rackspace's CloudFiles](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/).

Both of these services are very redundant, and you could use them as the back, and keep the primary storage on your server, or use them as the primary and keep a backup on your other web server. There are lots of options! Hops this info helps.